# My lua files are not read as lua in linux

Tags: linux, lua, dedicated-server

I've installed lua 5.4 on a google cloud vm, linux/debian os

but I have a file modoverrides.lua but running

$ file modoverrides.lua

on terminal it shows file type as ASCII text.

how can i make the system read it as a lua file? without adding #!/usr/bin/lua (the parent script breaks when i do that)

Comment: A Lua file *is* ASCII text. And what error do you get when you add the `#!` line? Any Lua interpreter should allow that.

Answer (score 0):

The `file` command puts out...

```
file mtest.lua 
mtest.lua: a /root/bin/lua script, ASCII text executable
```

...when the SHEBANG is: `#!/root/bin/lua`
With or without SHEBANG you can execute it with: `lua mtest.lua`
...if the `lua` interpreter is in the `PATH` variable.
From inside another lua script you can execute it with or without SHEBANG:

```
dofile("/path/to/mtest.lua")
```